# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\Response as array (Larravel/October CMS)

Tags: laravel, octobercms

i am having this erro clicking in on the menu (Build) so i dont understand. someone can help me please? Why this is happining in this line below?

```
     public function run($url = null)
    {
        $params = RouterHelper::segmentizeUrl($url);

        // Handle NotFoundHttpExceptions in the backend (usually triggered by abort(404))
        Event::listen('exception.beforeRender', function ($exception, $httpCode, $request) {
            if (!$this->cmsHandling && $exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
                return View::make('backend::404');
            }
        }, 1);

        /*
         * Database check
         */
        if (!App::hasDatabase()) {
            return Config::get('app.debug', false)
                ? Response::make(View::make('backend::no_database'), 200)
                : $this->passToCmsController($url);
        }

 the erro start happining at this line---------->

        $controllerRequest = $this->getRequestedController($url);
        if (!is_null($controllerRequest)) {
            return $controllerRequest['controller']->run(
                $controllerRequest['action'],
                $controllerRequest['params']
            );
        }

        /*
         * Fall back on Cms controller
         */
        return $this->passToCmsController($url);
    }
```

Comment: i am new in laravel and october cms and can't understand exactly what happen. But what you said can be usefull at all. i'm going to check a bit. and if u guys need more info to save me from just tell me

Comment: i just edit and share all the class for heping peope to have an idea may be that will be more clear then before...i dont know

Comment: can you show us what is `getRequestedController` ?

Comment: that little bit hard, but i can show all the public function to you. I did not create nothing. i dont know if you know but, as i am just using the CMS October so it just create some code alone and i just start to study October and Laravel at the same time.

Comment: Is this a new installation of OctoberCMS? What is your PHP version?

Comment: @PettisBrandon i think you are right. it is a old version of october and means that the Builder version received an update and that's why i am having this error.

Comment: @PettisBrandon i am using the php 7.2.4 and the builder plugin is in the version 1.0.26, my laravel version is 5.5.44 and October version is set to 461

Comment: Have you tried a clean install?

Comment: @PettisBrandon i dont have any idea about what is a clean install sorry...i am not an english native...but do you know if there is a way to rollback from a old version of a plugin? no answer i found anywhere

Comment: I don't think there is a way to roll back third party plugins. Is this clicking on a backend menu item for a custom plugin?

Comment: yes it is @PettisBrandon

Comment: @Gladiator could you post the [error log] (https://branmuffinstudios.com/storage/app/media/uploaded-files/1576606510710.png) after clicking on the plugin? I have been unable to duplicate this error.

Answer (score 0):

To make a View you don't need to make Response. Instead of

> Response::make(View::make('backend::no_database'), 200)

use

```
return View::make('backend::no_database');
```

or this for custom page

```
return View::make('author.plugin::backend.file'); # htm is on views/backend/file.htm
```

By the way check above on same file, it has `return View::make('backend::404');`